# Monad transformer in for comprehensions

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, for-comprehension

Consider:

```
def xs(c: String): Option[List[Long]] = ...

val ys: Stream[Long] = ...
```

Now I'd write a method something like:

```
def method(oc: Option[String]): Option[Long] = for { 
    c <- oc
    list <- xs(c)
} yield{        
    for {
        first <- ys.find(list contains _)
    } yield first
}
```

but of course this doesn't compile, since the inferred type is Option[Option[Long]].

Is there a way in terms of scala syntax and standard library to get an Option[Long]? I know I can pattern match, but the question if it can be done using for comprehensions only just arised.

---

Thanks to tenshi for the answer, that does the job, however I just encountered another example of my problem:

```
class T
class U
class A(t: String)(implicit x: T)
def getU(a: A): Option[U] = ...

def getU_2(oc: Option[String]): Option[U] = for{
   c <- oc
} yield{
   implicit val someImplicit: T = new T
   val a = A(c)

   getU(a)
}
```

I can add `a` in the for as: `a <- Some(A(c))` but what about the implicit? Should that imply a design change in my code?

Comment: Not sure about your intent, but you have 2 syntax error. You forgot `for` keyword at the beginning of the method body and you should use `<-` in `first = ys.find(list contains _)`.

Comment: Well I guess it's just too late for me to be coding or just too excited about writing in functional style :), this fixed it:

`def getU_2(oc: Option[String]): Option[U] = {
    implicit .. 
    for {
         c <- oc 
         a <- Some(A(c)) 
         u <- getU(a) 
    }  yield u
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using 2 nested `for` comprehensions? Shouldn't one do the job?

```
def method(oc: Option[String]): Option[Long] = 
    for { 
        c <- oc
        list <- xs(c)
        first <- ys.find(list contains _)
    } yield first
```

---

#### Update

About your second example. You can define implicit elsewhere and import it or define it in the beginning of the method, but I guess you want to make it's scope as narrow as possible. In this case you can use block directly in the `for` comprehension:

```
def getU_2(oc: Option[String]): Option[U] = for {
   c <- oc
   a <- {
       implicit val someImplicit: T = new T
       getU(new A(c))
   }
} yield a
```

or (probably the simplest) provide implicit parameter explicitly:

```
def getU_2(oc: Option[String]): Option[U] = for {
   c <- oc
   a <- getU(new A(c)(new T))
} yield a
```